# rxjs observable - avoid recursive assignments

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I am looking for ideas for improving the code below, I will start by describing the problem and give my solution which I am looking to improve.

The code is Angular 4 (TS)

```
herelistOfItems$: Observable<Array<Item>>;

// Getting list of items from the backend 
init() {
  this.listOfItems$ = http.get('/getItems'); 
}

// - Check if item already exits (show error and stop if exists)
// - If not add the item (http request)
// - Refresh by getting get the updated list from the backend (http request)
onClickAddNewItem(newItem: Item) {
   this.listOfItems$ = this.listOfItems$
                             .filter(/* validate item is not exits */)
                             .concatMap(_ => http.post('/addItem', newItem))
                             .switchMap(_ => http.get('/getItems'))
                             .catch((err) => ...);
}
```

the HTML code will look something like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listOfItems$ | async">...
```

The problem with this code is the recoursive assignment `this.listOfItems$ = this.listOfItems$...`

one possible solution can be

```
onClickAddNewItem(newItem: Item) {
   this.listOfItems$
       .filter(/* validate item is not exits */)
       .concatMap(_ => http.post('/addItem', newItem))
       .subscribe(_ => this.listOfItems$ = http.get(...), err => ... );

}
```

I am looking for a more elegant way to refresh the list without subscribing to it, any ideas?
(I know I can solve it with ngrx\store but I don't use it in this project)

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not sure that you want to use `switchMap` for `addItem` since this will cancel a previous item addition if it didn't complete before attempting the next item addition.

Comment: Good point
since this is HTTP request I am not worried about the request being canceled by another event (there is only one response event)
But better practices, I have changed the example to use `concatMap`

Answer (score 2):

You can create an observable stream from click events where you would normally run `onClickAddNewItem`.

```
@ViewChild() addButton;

this.listOfItems$ = this.http.get('/getItems').pipe(
  switchMap(items => fromEvent(this.addButton.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
    startWith(items),
    filter(/* ... */)
    mergeMap(newItem => this.http.post('/addItem', { newItem })),
    switchMap(() => this.http.get('/getItems')),
  ),
);
```